# How should I itrate over csv file row by row to get 1 prediction at the time

Tags: python, pandas, csv, catboost

My code:

```
counter = 0
while True :
    try :     
        test = pd.read_csv('test.csv' , nrows = 1 , skiprows = (counter) )
        counter += 1
    except:
        sleep(1)
        print('sleep')
        continue

    test = test.iloc[::,::]

    print('counter' , counter)

    test  = test[newx] # the same model trained features
    print('########### Binary classification is loading #############')
    print('test' , test)
    result1 = GB_model.predict(test) # lunch predication 

    #print(result1)

    print('......Binary classfication result......')

    for i in result1:
        if i == 1:
            print('Attack traffic!!')
        else:
            print('Benign')
```

example of the rows and columns in the csv file

https://pmqu-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/3710137_upm_edu_sa/EWwYIThGjwhLnaHM-0OirdcBwQyIHfy8o1WG_M0tcohJOg?e=n8cvQR

the error , Just the first rows will be predicted then next rows will come up with this error which i think it appears because the next rows will get inside the predict function without rows headers (features)

```
└─# python script.py                                                                                                
/home/kali/Desktop/conda/Desktop/envs/project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/compat.py:36: FutureWarning: pandas.Int64Index is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.Index with the appropriate dtype instead.
  from pandas import MultiIndex, Int64Index
counter 1
########### Binary classification is loading #############
test    protocol  flow_duration  tot_fwd_pkts  tot_bwd_pkts  ...  init_bwd_win_byts  fwd_seg_size_min  active_mean  idle_mean
0        17   5.003721e+06             4             0  ...                  0                 8          0.0        0.0

[1 rows x 31 columns]
......Binary classfication result......
Benign
:( no attack traffic maybe next time
counter 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/cicflowmeter-0.1.6/project/script.py", line 90, in <module>
    test  = test[newx]
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/conda/Desktop/envs/project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3511, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns._get_indexer_strict(key, "columns")[1]
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/conda/Desktop/envs/project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 5782, in _get_indexer_strict
    self._raise_if_missing(keyarr, indexer, axis_name)
  File "/home/kali/Desktop/conda/Desktop/envs/project/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 5842, in _raise_if_missing
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['protocol', 'flow_duration', 'tot_fwd_pkts', 'tot_bwd_pkts',\n       'totlen_fwd_pkts', 'totlen_bwd_pkts', 'fwd_pkt_len_mean',\n       'fwd_pkt_len_std', 'bwd_pkt_len_mean', 'flow_byts_s', 'flow_pkts_s',\n       'flow_iat_std', 'flow_iat_min', 'fwd_iat_tot', 'fwd_iat_min',\n       'bwd_iat_tot', 'bwd_iat_min', 'fwd_psh_flags', 'fwd_urg_flags',\n       'bwd_pkts_s', 'fin_flag_cnt', 'rst_flag_cnt', 'psh_flag_cnt',\n       'ack_flag_cnt', 'urg_flag_cnt', 'down_up_ratio', 'init_fwd_win_byts',\n       'init_bwd_win_byts', 'fwd_seg_size_min', 'active_mean', 'idle_mean'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

Comment: Hi OMAR, just some general tips: don't open the file in every iteration - that is bad and heavy on IO. Also, don't use a "bare except", IE an `except` statement without an exception. You should catch the specific exception you are trying to handle.

Comment: if you don't want read all data at once then `read_csv` has option to read in `chunks`

Comment: better show example data from your file - it seems your file is NOT correct CSV (which have the same columns in every row) but some mix of rows with different content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want to read all at once then you can read in chunks (using rows number)

```
import pandas as pd

for row in pd.read_csv('filename.csv', chunksize=1):
    print(row)
```

But your real problem can be that your file is NOT correct CSV.

In CSV every row need the same columns but you have row different values in different rows and you should read it as normal text file and parse every row in different way (using own code)

Comment: thanks for the answer it is actually worked but the issue is we want to make this process infinite until  i close it that's why I have used while true and if nothing we just wait for the new input ,  however I am trying to read the chunk and store it in a var but it is not working . the iterator is better but not endless  .

Comment: And that is the error with while true declared var >>> 'TextFileReader' object is not subscriptable<<< due the use of chunk when i am assigning the new headers

Comment: if you don't add new rows to file then `for`-loop should work the same as `while True`  And if you add new rows then manybe better use normal `csv` instead of `pandas`. OR read as normal text file and parse it manually.

Comment: The csv file will be created and filled automatically by another tool , here i will just take it and predict the rows one by one till it finished the script will wait for another rows to be filled and predict accordingly

Comment: maybe you should use some queue instead of file